# Implement ReplyKeyboardMarkup in POST url

Tags: telegram-bot

How to implement **ReplyKeyboardMarkup** in POST qwery for **sendMessage** method?

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=test&reply_markup= ..... ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass json as parameters in URL, you should encode it. So a URL like this:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=test&reply_markup={"keyboard": [["Button"]]}`

changes to: 
`https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=123&text=test&reply_markup=%7B%22keyboard%22%3A+%5B%5B%22Button%22%5D%5D%7D`

You can use online URL encoder/decoder like [this](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) one.

More information on URL encoding:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Can you describe your answer in details or add some helpful links?

Comment: Thanks, Vahid. It's very helpful.

Comment: please help me in link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c